# ASP.NET MVC3 project throws immediate 404 when run locally in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

When I run my ASP.NET MVC3 app locally in VS2010, it is throwing an immediate 404. This project used to work previously and I'm tearing my hair out to figure out what's going on.

The error message is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is 
temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that 
it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /
```

I've tried setting breakpoints in the controller but it's never hit.  I have no idea how to debug or fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you expecting to load when you start the application?  The Index action?  Can you list that controller and action here?  And does a view exist for that corresponding action with the same name as the action in a folder which has a name corresponding to that controller name?  Have you changed the routes defined in the global.asax or is it still using the default route that is defined?  If you have changed can you also list here.

Comment: Hard to diagnose your issue without more detail.  You may want to look into a route debugger for help (e.g. [Phil Haack's](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is from the routing engine.

The reason your breakpoints in the controller are not hit is because execution never gets that far. If a request doesn't match a route that would steer it to your controller you get a 404 (content/controller not found).

Of note is that the built-in routing engine does not work out of the box on xp/win2k3 machines.

Comment: This was it. The error was in the routing engine where I had an issue with the default route.

Answer (score 0):

routing engine couldn't find the default page ex: `/Home/Index` that mean Index action in HomeController.

Check the global.asax for routing. There should be code like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                );
}
```